# gnome-builder crashes when trying to open project

Tags: gnome, crash, gnome-builder

When I try to open a project in `gnome-builder`, whether it's by clicking one of the projects on this screen it starts up on (I have put a big black box over some more private stuff):

[image: "Select a Project" screen in <code>gnome-builder</code>]

Or if I use the `New` button and select an already existing project, it just closes. And over the course of the time that I started the application I have been getting these errors in Terminal:

```
22:14:57.0356                         libpeas[13410]:  WARNING: Error importing plugin 'html_preview_plugin':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-builder/plugins/html_preview_plugin/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Builder
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 114, in load_module
    introspection_module = get_introspection_module(namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 271, in get_introspection_module
    module = IntrospectionModule(namespace, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 120, in __init__
    repository.require(namespace, version)
gi.RepositoryError: Typelib file for namespace 'Ggit', version '1.0' not found
22:14:57.0356                         libpeas[13410]:  WARNING: Error loading plugin 'html_preview_plugin'
22:14:57.0481                         libpeas[13410]:  WARNING: Error importing plugin 'jedi_plugin':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-builder/plugins/jedi_plugin.py", line 34, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Ide
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 114, in load_module
    introspection_module = get_introspection_module(namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 271, in get_introspection_module
    module = IntrospectionModule(namespace, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 120, in __init__
    repository.require(namespace, version)
gi.RepositoryError: Typelib file for namespace 'Ggit', version '1.0' not found
22:14:57.0481                         libpeas[13410]:  WARNING: Error loading plugin 'jedi_plugin'
22:14:57.0490                         libpeas[13410]:  WARNING: Error importing plugin 'python_gi_imports_completion':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-builder/plugins/python_gi_imports_completion.py", line 36, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Ide
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 114, in load_module
    introspection_module = get_introspection_module(namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 271, in get_introspection_module
    module = IntrospectionModule(namespace, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 120, in __init__
    repository.require(namespace, version)
gi.RepositoryError: Typelib file for namespace 'Ggit', version '1.0' not found
22:14:57.0490                         libpeas[13410]:  WARNING: Error loading plugin 'python_gi_imports_completion'
```

And when I ask it to open a project it exists with this final error message:

```
22:15:39.0312               gb-greeter-window[13410]:  WARNING: Typelib file for namespace 'Ggit', version '1.0' not found
```

So am I just doing something wrong or is this a bug which I should report?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.18
```

**Package Information:**

```
gnome-builder:
  Installed: 3.18.0-0ubuntu1~wily4
  Candidate: 3.18.0-0ubuntu1~wily4
  Version table:
 *** 3.18.0-0ubuntu1~wily4 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: From the looks of it, you're using an experimental PPA to install GNOME Builder, and bugs are to be expected. If you want to debug it and narrow down the problem further, you could install debugging symbols and give us a backtrace (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash).

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste: How exactly do I install the debugging symbols? Because I tried to install `gnome-builder-dbg` as it suggested, but it said that the package could not be found.

Comment: You're using Ubuntu 15.10, which means you don't have -dbg packages anymore. Have a look at the Ubuntu Wiki here (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash#Non-built-in_debug_symbol_packages_.28.2A-dbgsym.29). However, you got GNOME Builder from a PPA, and I'm not sure if ddebs are built for PPAs.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste: Seems to have been due to a missing dependency (see [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/741525/364819) for details)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason Gnome Builder crashes is that it has a dependency on a Git library but it's not automatically installed when you install Builder (it's [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=801648;msg=2) specifically). You can get your Gnome Builder to run by manually installing the `gir1.2-git2-glib-1.0` package from the repositories for now with:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-git2-glib-1.0
```